# Apache, grouping subdomains

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up some basic virtualhosts in Apache2, within the domain
`nosoftpatents.com` (invented). I'm supposed to have two subdomains, friendly
and previous, each of them accessible from two ports, 80 and 8800, that are to
be linked to the `stable` and `devel` subdirectories of each domain. So far, I
have this:

```yaml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName friendly.nosoftpatents.com        
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nopatents/friendly/stable
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName previous.nosoftpatents.com        
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nopatents/previous/stable
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8800>
    ServerName friendly.nosoftpatents.com        
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nopatents/friendly/devel    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8800>
    ServerName previous.nosoftpatents.com        
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nopatents/previous/devel
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing it? Some way of grouping the hosts from the
same port?

Comment: There is no other elegant way to achieve what you want. Your way is the minimal way ;) However, (for the future) if all your sub-domains were on the same port then you could group them by DocumentRoot with using `ServerAlias` directive.